# Alarm Manager doesn't work in application with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager, geofencing

I'm doing an application, that uses [geofences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo-fence) to track our events and I want to create an alarm manager, which is activated daily and adds geofences for current day events (taken from database).

I needed to create an activity to use geofences and in this activity, I put [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver). It seems that it's not working at all. I don't even get any logs from these activities. I don't know why, but I suppose something can be wrong in Manifest. I would be grateful if someone would look at this.

Class MyScheduler:

```
public class MyScheduler extends Activity {


protected static final String TAG = "MyScheduler";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRecurringAlarm(this);
}

private void setRecurringAlarm(Context context) {

    Log.i(TAG, "setReccuringAlarm");
    Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1:00"));
    updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Tasks.class);
    PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(
            Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            updateTime.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, recurringDownload);
    }
}
```

Tasks with BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class Tasks  extends Activity
implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<Status> {
Context context;
final public static String ONE_TIME = "onetime";

EventDAO eventDAO;

protected static final String TAG = "MyGeofence";

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String today = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
List<Event> eventsList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = getApplicationContext();

    mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
    mGeofencePendingIntent = null;
    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME,
            MODE_PRIVATE);
    mGeofencesAdded = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY, false);

    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

/// geofences mathods, not needed

BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(ONE_TIME, "Executed Tasks.Java File");
        //Some task here for every morning
        eventDAO = new EventDAO(context);
        eventsList = eventDAO.getComingEvents(today, today);

        for( Event event : eventsList){
            String place = event.getEndLocalisationX();
            Log.i(ONE_TIME, place);

            Double lat = Double.parseDouble(event.getEndLocalisationY());
            Double lng = Double.parseDouble(event.getEndLocalisationX());
            MY_PLACES.put(place, new LatLng(lat, lng));
        }

        populateGeofenceList();
        addGeofences();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

And part of the manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <activity android:name=".MyScheduler"/>
    <activity android:name=".Tasks"/>

    <receiver android:name=".Tasks" >
     </receiver>
```

I can add, that everything with geofences works well, so I didn't put the geofences code above, as it's easier to read. Hope someone will be able to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a PendingIntent to send a broadcast, but you specified an Activity class (Tasks). You shouldn't set an alarm to interrupt the user with a UI, if Android even allows that. You should move your Broadcast receiver in to an outer class such as TasksReceiver:

```
public class TasksReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(ONE_TIME, "Executed Tasks.Java File");
    //Some task here for every morning
    EventDAO eventDAO = new EventDAO(context);
    List<Event> eventsList = eventDAO.getComingEvents(today, today);

    for( Event event : eventsList){
        String place = event.getEndLocalisationX();
        Log.i(ONE_TIME, place);

        Double lat = Double.parseDouble(event.getEndLocalisationY());
        Double lng = Double.parseDouble(event.getEndLocalisationX());
        MY_PLACES.put(place, new LatLng(lat, lng));
    }

    populateGeofenceList();
    addGeofences();
   }
}
```

and specify that class name for the pending intent and the receiver declaration in the manifest would look like:

```
<receiver android:name=".TasksReceiver" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. That's what I tried at the beggining, but I didn't know how to use geofencing methods from other activity in broadcast receiver. I know that it can be a very silly question, but I don't have any experience with java. That's why I found how to do a broadcast IN the activity.

Comment: Simply put, that's not going to work. I don't know what you mean by "use geofencing methods from other activity" but whatever functionality comprises "activated daily and adds geofences for curent day events (taken from database)" needs to be in a standalone broadcast receiver.

Comment: Yep, I was stupid, thanks. I don't know why I had this problem. Thanks a lot ;)